# OWLApi include import closure for getAnnotations()

Tags: ontology, owl-api

I am working with OWLAPI v3.5.2 on iterating over all classes via `getClassesInSignature(true)`, including the imports closure of the current ontology, and I am wondering if there's a similar way to include the imports closure for `getAnnotations()` as well.

A very basic example would be the following:

```
for (OWLClass klass: ontology.getClassesInSignature(true)) {
   for (OWLAnnotation annotations: klass.getAnnotations(ontology, datafactory.getRDFSLabel())) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Currently, only *rdfs:labels* contained in the *root* ontology are found while classes originated from `owl:imports` are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's available in 4.x, in OWLOntology and EntitySearcher. Not supported in 3.5.2 - it would be an interface change, so it's not going to be backported.

Comment: Thanks! Would the only work around be to loop over all imported ontologies to search for annotations? (Apart from upgrading to v4)

Comment: Yes, there's no convenience method that I know of.

Comment: @Ignazio how is this possible in 4.x? Looking at both `OWLOntology` and `EntitySearcher` and the only thing I can find is `getAnnotationAssertionAxioms` which doesn't include the closure. Some pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OWLAPI's `getAnnotations()` method does not directly support including annotations from the imports closure.

However, you can manually implement this by traversing the import closure and applying `getAnnotations()` on each ontology in the import closure.

Here's a rough example of how to do this:

```
    // Fetch the import closure
    Set<OWLOntology> importClosure = ontology.getImportsClosure();
    
    // For each class in the ontology
    for (OWLClass klass: ontology.getClassesInSignature(true)) {
    
       // For each ontology in the import closure
       for (OWLOntology importedOntology : importClosure) {
       
           // Fetch and process the annotations
           for (OWLAnnotation annotation: klass.getAnnotations(importedOntology, dataFactory.getRDFSLabel())) {
               // Process annotation...
           }
       }
    }
```

In this example, `klass.getAnnotations()` is called on each ontology in the import closure (including the base ontology itself). This should fetch the annotations from all imported ontologies as well as the base ontology.

Remember, this is only a basic example. Depending on your application, you may need to add error checking, handle duplicate annotations from different ontologies, or add other complexities as required. In any case, please verify this approach against the documentation and behaviour of your specific OWLAPI version.